# Changing an arraylist size while using an enhanced for loop

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrentmodification

I'm trying to play war, and whenever you compare two cards `if(c.getValue() > Player2.get(x).getValue()){...` I'm finding the winner and redistributing player one's card and player two's card to a hold pile, `ArrayList<Card> Pile = new ArrayList<Card>();`,  and then distributing that pile to the winner based off of a boolean however the console is throwing "concurrentModificationException" I do not know any other way to approach this. How do I add to an arraylist of ever changing size after comparing two arraylists of objects?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck {
    ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    ArrayList<Card> player1 = new ArrayList<Card>();
    ArrayList<Card> player2 = new ArrayList<Card>();
    ArrayList<Card> pile = new ArrayList<Card>();
    boolean winner;

    public Deck(){

    }
    public void createDeck(){
        for(int i =0; i<4; i++){        
            for(int j =1; j<15;j++){            
                if(i==0) deck.add(new Card("Spades", j));                   
                if(i==1) deck.add(new Card("Hearts", j));
                if(i==2) deck.add(new Card("Clubs", j));
                if(i==3) deck.add(new Card("Diamonds",j));

            }
        }
    }
    public void splitDeck(){
        for(int i = 0; i< 52;i++){
            int r = (int) (Math.random()*(51-i));
            if(i%2==0){
                player1.add(deck.get(r));
            }
            else{
                player2.add(deck.get(r));
            }
            deck.remove(r);
        }

    }
    public int [] war(){

        int[]score = {0,0};

        for(Card c : player1){
            int x = player1.indexOf(c);
            if(c.getValue() > player2.get(x).getValue()){
                winner = true;
                score[0]++;
                pile.add(player1.get(x));
                pile.add(player2.get(x));
                distributeCards();
            }
            else if(c.getValue() <player2.get(x).getValue()) score[1]++;
            distributeCards();
        }

        return score;
    }   

    public void distributeCards(){

            if(winner==true){
                for(int i = 0; i<pile.size(); i++){
                    player1.add(pile.get(i));
                }
            }
            else{
                for(int i = 0; i<pile.size(); i++){
                    player2.add(pile.get(i));
                }
            }
        }


    public String warGame(){
        String print= "";
        for(Card c : player1){
            int x = player1.indexOf(c);
            if(c.getValue() > player2.get(x).getValue()){

                print+= "\n"+"Player1 won";
            }
            else if(c.getValue() <player2.get(x).getValue())
                print+="\n"+"Player2 won";

            else if(c.getValue() ==player2.get(x).getValue())
                print+= "\n"+"Its a tie";
        }

        return print;

    }

}
```

error in the console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at Deck.war(Deck.java:69)
    at War.main(War.java:6)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error message with the line which it points to in the code

Comment: Line 69 points to `distributeCards()` inside the `if` block or outside.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Following these suggestions as well as following good code formatting practices will allow others (such as us!) to better understand your code, and more importantly, will allow your future self to better understand just what you were thinking 6 months ago when you wrote the code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I try, for some part, to follow this, as you may be able to tell in my methods I do follow the xX structure but I often do not share my code unless with a friend for review, but I will keep that in mind the next time I post and will change that now. It is probably something I should hammer into my brain

Comment: The `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs on this line: `for(Card c : player1) {` (because that's the only line in the method `war` that invokes `Iterator.next()`)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a CopyOnWriteArrayList, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html. The essence of it is CopyOnWriteArrayList's do not throw concurrent modification exceptions (so you can add to them while iterating over them), however this comes at the cost of copying the underlying data each time there is a write. Since your use case is a war game this performance but will likely not be that noticeable.

Comment: After reading the general, it almost seems as if I would have to almost restructure the rest of my methods is this true? I will read further in depth tomorrow but it seems promising.

Comment: You should be able to just switch out your ArrayList's with CopyOnWriteArrayList's.  Note while your at it I would change your declarations to something like this List<Card>  pile = new CopyOnArrayList<Card>();.  This is known as programming to the interface, what it buys you is if you had passed your lists around you would have to change each place that took an ArrayList, also all downstream code is dependent on the given implementation.  By using the interface instead you can change the implementing type of list without affecting other code.

Comment: Adjusted my answer because of your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try out [`ListIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) which has support for a remove/add method during the iteration itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to modify an ArrayList you are iterating, the solution is pretty simple:

```
private List<YourObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
public void removeFromList(){
     List<YourObject> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
     for (Object o: list) {
         o.doSomething();
         if (yourCondition){
             tempList.add(o);
         }
     }
     list = tempList;
}
```

This is for removing objects, but the implementation for adding them is also very simple.

Comment: What exactly would o.doSomething(); relate to in this project? also list = tempList; how will that help me add from hand 1 and hand 2 to the winner? Wouldn't that just make list A equal to List B without card B?

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that to avoid concurrent modifications to a list you can make a new list with the needed objects and then copy it over.

Comment: I tried this with "pile" the card that is dealt by each player is put in the pile, and then distributed to the winner

Comment: Yes I did I will post my answer, i ended up rechanging my structure